# Monitoring File Changes

Tags: command-line, vbscript

```
Call CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(some.exe,0,False)
```

I'm using that line to call a .exe that returns some text, but can also write it to a file.

I would use `.Exec` instead of `.Run` to get the results directly but then the script hangs.

I really don't want a timer checking if the output file is created or modified.

What I need is a way to catch an event somehow. Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Maybe you can call WaitForSingleObject, but a quick search on Google doesn't show how to do this from VBScript.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with monitoring file changes?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that it might either return it or write it to a file, does that mean that after the process has written to the file it'll exit?

If so, you could just call the [Shell.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method with the `bWaitOnReturn` parameter set to `True` and your script would wait for the process to finish before it continued.

Otherwise, if the process might write a file and then still continue to run, then I think you will have to poll to check if it exists, or possibly you could create a C# or VB.Net exe that uses [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) (or a normal Win32 exe that uses the API `FindFirstChangeNotification`) to look for the creation of the file and when it finds one it immediately exists and then you could run that process with `bWaitOnReturn` set to `True`, but that's probably just overcomplicating things.

Comment: When the .exe finishes it exits. bWaitOnReturn will make the script hang. It has to be VBScript.